# Displaying server time on jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, datetime

I am displaying `server time` on a `jsp` page, and in order to display correct time, I have to call that `jsp` page to refresh the displayed time which leads to many `requests` to the `server`.

Can anyone suggest any improvement on the way I'm displaying server time on `jsp` page without sending `request` frequently?

```
function displayserver(){
    $.post("DisplayServerTime.jsp","",function(data,status, req){
         $("#DisplayTimeSection").text(req.responseText.trim());
    });
}

$(function(){
setInterval(
function(){
    displayserver();
}
, 30000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the server time when you first load the page, then find out the time difference between the client's time and the server's time.

Second, run recurrently a function (using setInterval()). On each invocation get the client time and add the time difference you got at the first step, then display it.

You'll need to run the interval function something like twice per second to be sure you don't skip seconds.

Answer (score 0):

> without sending request frequently.

While loading the page get the server  time in long  and create a [`Date(millis)`  Object with `Javascript`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Then use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) with 1 sec and display.

In you Jsp

```
var jsVar=  <% dateMillis %>;   // server millis
```

and javascript date formation

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(jsVar);   // server millis ex :1332403882588
```

Then show in JS

```
var x = document.getElementById("timelable");
x.innerHTML=d.getMilliseconds(); // Modify as per your format
```

Then

```
window.setInterval(Yourfunction,milliseconds);
```

Then in your `Yourfunction`  add *1 sec* to your  millis  and refresh `lable`

Comment: He asked for server time, not client time.

Comment: `While loading the page get the time in long`, That is from server

Comment: It is a little bit confusing. I though you get the time from client side too.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Yes, Mentioned as server.

Comment: He probably wants the date, not the milliseconds. `x.innerHTML = d;` seems better.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily. Just send to the client the `server time` and add a client-side `setInterval` that will get the time, increment by 1 second and set the time back in the page.

Note that if you want the `client time`, you can get the time as easy as `new Date()` in JS and apply the `setInterval` too.

Comment: thanks Silviu , i do not want client time as it may be wrong . can i do this using jquery?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with jQuery, but JS will do as well. All you have to do is to send the server time in your JSP to have the initial server time.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** Get the server Date object on your page using `request.getAttribute("serverDate");` or `session.getAttribute("serverDate");`

**Step 2 :**  Create a javascript Object from the date recieved in step 1

**Step 3 :** Add a client-side `setInterval` it will increment ***Step2*** object by 1 second and set the time back in the page.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the fact that setInterval calls your update function with the necessary accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to call the time.jsp once every five times when the displayserver method is called. For the other 4 times when the time.jsp is not called, we update a javascript Date object and display it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jsVar=0;
var d = new Date();
var timeInterval = 3000;

var doPost=true;
var postCount=0;


function displayserver(){
    if(doPost && postCount == 0){
        $.post("time.jsp","")
         .done(function(msg){
            jsVar = msg;
            doPost = false;
        });
    }else{
        postCount++;
        jsVar = d.getTime() + timeInterval;
        if(postCount == 4){
            postCount=0;
            doPost = true;
        }
    }
    d.setTime(jsVar);
    $("#DisplayTimeSection").text(d);
}

$(function(){
setInterval(
function(){
    displayserver();
}
, timeInterval);
});

</script>
```

Comment: time.jsp will be called every 15 seconds and time update will happen every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Add a label where ever you want to show the server Time

```
<strong>Server Time&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><label id="timelable"></label>
```

And then add the following java script code at the end of the jsp inside the body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);
        var jsVar=  <%=java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()%>;
        var timeZoneOffset=<%=java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis())%>;

        jsVar=jsVar+timeZoneOffset;
        function myTimer() {
        jsVar=jsVar+1000;
        var d = new Date(jsVar);
        var t=d.toUTCString();
    document.getElementById("timelable").innerHTML = t;
}

        </script>
```

Thats it now you will see the server time running in you jsp.