# JSP Display Server Date and Time Using Server Timezone

Tags: java, jsp

I have an RHEL6 Linux server in Mexico running my application. The server timezone is CDT. So when I issue the "date" command on the Linux command line I get the correct date and time which is an hour behind me. (I'm in EDT).

However, when I use the java.util.date object and display the current server date in a JSP, it is displaying the proper date and time for my timezone.

For instance I use:

```
<% ...
Date local = new Date();
out.write("'" + local + "'");
... %>
```

This would show, say,

> Tue Aug 22 14:39:13 EDT 2017

, the date and time I am writing this. But I need to display

> Tue Aug 22 13:39:13 CDT 2017

which is the actual date and time of the server.

I'm somewhat new to Java, JSP. So I'm not sure exactly how to get the output the way I need it.

Thank You

Comment: [Displaying server time to jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515138/displaying-server-time-on-jsp-page)

Comment: @BerkleyLamb I looked at the SO question/answer you cited prior to asking my question. From what I saw, it does not address my specific need of ensuring the date/time is properly displayed in the JSP. and I'm currently not using javascript to constantly poll the server for the date time. Thank you, though, for your input

Comment: @NimrodArgov, I need to look at your suggested SO post a little deeper. It may actually lead to some insight. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Question is a duplicate of many others, so briefly…

Do not use troublesome legacy date.time classes, now supplanted by java.time classes.

`Date` is always in UTC yet its `toString` method dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone. Confusing. One of *many* reasons to avoid legacy classes.

Always specify your desired/expected time zone. Never rely implicitly on the JVM’s current time zone. So as a programmer you should never care what zone the deployed server may be set to. That default can change at any moment during runtime so it is unreliable.

Never use the 3-4 letter pseudo time zones like CDT or EDT. They are not actual zones, they are not standardized, and they are not even unique! [Real time zones](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) named `continent/region`.

```
ZonedDateTime.now(
    ZoneId.of( "America/Mexico_City" ) 
).toString()
```

For other formats see `DateTimeFormatter`. Notice the `ofLocalized…` methods.

How to get the user’s desired time zone? You can try to get a default offset via the web browser. As I recall browsers return only a current offset, not a full time zone. But ultimately the only way to be sure is to ask the user explicitly.

Comment: thank you for your input. Unfortunately, this is legacy code I am working with and may not be able to update it accordingly

Comment: @PaulStoner (A) If you are capturing the current moment, and generating a string, then how would you be tied into old code? (B) Furthermore, FYI, you can convert to/from java.time via new methods added to the old classes. So you can always interact with old code while sticking with only java.time in your new code. The old date-time classes really are an awful mess and should be avoided.